# Not able to pull or push to my github repo

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-push

Here's what I did.

1. Made changes to my README directly in my github repo with 3 commits.
2. made 4 more commits locally without pulling those  3 commits in.

Now when I try to push it says pull those remote commits first but when I do git pull it show error.

```
warning: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following commands sometime before your next pull:

  git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
  git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
  git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
```

So I just ran the command `git config pull.ff only`

And now when I pull this is what it says `fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you paste that as text in the question? Do not worry about formatting. We will help you by formatting it after you post it so you can see how it's done after the fact.

Comment: And FFs will _never_ work on diverging branches. FF only works if the branch that you are on is an ancestor of the branch you are merging (so, no divergence).

Comment: warning: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
commands sometime before your next pull:

  git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
  git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
  git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only

Comment: Paste the text in the question, remove the image, please.

Comment: @eftshift0 Edited the question as you said. I hope it is clear now, please help me, is it possible to revert the commit I made in github without making another commit ? So that I can push the changes I made locally.

Comment: if it's a feature branch, feel free to rebase it on top of the main branch: `git fetch origin; git rebase origin/main` (adjust name of remote and base branch if necessary). The trick is that you can safely rebase branches _if they are not being used by anyone else_.... feature branches are _normally_ safe to rebase until you merge them into the main branch. Having said that, you should consider getting rid of `pull.ff only` because that does _not_ make sense to use if you are working on feature branches and expect to pull changes committed on the upstream branch (because it implies divergence)

Comment: I got rid of `pull.ff only` as you said, and again tried to pull, and this time it succesfully pulled with a message `Merge made by the 'ort' strategy.`

Comment: I successfully pushed my local commits as well, thanks for your help @eftshift0

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... the problem with your current setup (with `pull.ff only`) is that it is a *very* restrictive setup.

Suppose this startup diagram

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- (main)
```

You start a feature branch from main:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- (main)
               ^
                \- (feature)
```

After a while, the chart is like this:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- F <- G <- (main)
               ^
                \- (feature)
```

Notice how `feature` has not moved. At this moment, `feature` is pointing to an ancestor of `main` and so a fast-forward would work, which would do this:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- F <- G <- (main)
                         ^
                          \- (feature)
```

Because, as the name implies, a fast-forward only moves the pointer, it does not do any rebasing/merging in the process.

However, on a normal feature branch, you would introduce commit, so you would have something like this:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- F <- G <- (main)
               ^
                \- I <- J <- K <- (feature)
```

And in this case, given that `feaure` is not pointing to an ancestor of `main`, it is **not** possible to do a FF.... but your setup is asking to only run pulls if it's a FF.... so, it fails. You need to be able to either rebase or merge for this to work so `pull.ff only` is a **no-go**.

Comment: wow, this was really informative, now I think I understand what the actual problem is

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm not *disagreeing* with [eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74320868/1256452) here, in that I agree that setting `pull.ff` to `only` is restrictive.  But I would note that this restriction might well be a good idea.  It's one *I* would want, and in fact, I've configured Git this way myself.

When `git pull` or `git pull origin branch` fails with the `fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting` error, it's time to inspect the incoming commits, using `git log`, e.g.:

```
git log --graph --decorate --left-right --boundary ...@{u}
```

(or the same with `--oneline` added), or:

```
git log --oneline ..@{u}
```

to show "incoming" commits (already fetched, just not yet merged or rebased-upon) and:

```
git log --oneline @{u}..
```

to show "local-only" commits (existing in my repository but not in the other Git from which I've fetched).  These `git log` commands all make use of the `@{u}` construct, which is short for `branch@{upstream}`.

The *upstream* of a branch name is something you can set, but typically it's already set correctly by the time you're doing this.  For instance, if you are on your `develop` branch, the "upstream" of `develop` is probably `origin/develop`, which is probably correct.  This particular concept of upstream—Git is bad here and uses the word *upstream* to mean multiple different concepts<sup>1</sup>—is the one we're talking about here: whatever branch you're "on" right now, it's the "upstream" `origin/` version of this same name that you probably want to use with `git rebase`, or `git merge`, or whatever operation it is you want to do.

Writing out `develop@{upstream}` would do the trick, but what if you're not *on* `develop` after all, but rather on `feature/long`?  Now you have to write `feature/long@{upstream}`.  Git has a simple solution: if you leave out the *branch name*, and just write `@{upstream}`, it means *the upstream of the current branch*.  So that's what we do here.  We can also write `HEAD@{upstream}` to be more explicit, but we can leave out the `HEAD` part when it's obvious.

Meanwhile, the *two*-dot notation, `HEAD..HEAD@{upstream}` or `A..B` or `main..origin/main` or whatever also has a very specific meaning.  With `git log`—like *most* Git commands<sup>2</sup>—it means "using the commit I specify on the right, find lots of commits; stop finding commits when you find those using the commit I specify on the left."  This means that `HEAD..HEAD@{upstream}` or `HEAD@{upstream}..HEAD` is actually rather useful.

If you're not used to Git, the last paragraph probably just seems like a lot of random words.  But using the same kinds of diagrams that eftshift0 drew, we can make sense out of this.  Here's what is going on:

```
          I--J   <-- feature/long (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/feature/long
```

Here, I'm "on" my branch `feature/long`.  Its upstream is `origin/feature/long`.  I, and they, both started with common-starting-point commit `H`: I made two commits `I-J`, and they—whoever they are—made two commits `K-L`.

When I run `git fetch` against origin—remember that the *first* command that `git pull` runs is always `git fetch`—I got their `K-L` commits, and my Git software updated my `origin/feature/long` to remember commit `L`, which I now have.  So that's why the diagram looks like this: that's what is now in my Git repository.  (Their Git repository lacks commits `I-J` entirely, as yet.)

Now, note that `HEAD` literally *means* `feature/long`, and `HEAD@{upstream}` means `origin/feature/long`.  Note further that `A..B` means "commits found by starting at `B` and working backwards, excluding commits you can find by starting at `A` and working backwards".  If we put these together with `HEAD` and `HEAD@{upstream}` as the `A` and `B` parts, we're asking Git to find:

- commits like `L` that we can find with `origin/feature/long`;
- including commits like `K` that we can find by starting there and working backwards, as Git likes to do;
- but **not** including commits like `J`, `I`, and `H`.

The result is that `git log HEAD..HEAD@{upstream}` shows commits `L` and `K`, and then stops!  That's exactly the set of "incoming" commits.

Meanwhile, reversing the two arguments, with `git log HEAD@{upstream}..HEAD`, shows commits `J` and then `I`, and then stops: these are exactly the commits I have that they don't.

Adding `--graph` and/or `--oneline` helps display these sorts of things better.  Since we can drop the word `HEAD` when it's clear to Git that we mean `HEAD`, and since `@{u}` is short for `@{upstream}`, we're allowed to write `..@{u}` and `@{u}..`.

In fact, I use `git log ..@{u}` often enough that I made a Git alias for it:

```
[alias]
    lin = log ..@{u}
```

This allows me to run `git lin` to `l`og (or look at) `in`coming commits.  (I have an `incoming` alias that includes `--oneline`, and a `git outgoing` that has the `--oneline` and swaps the `@{u}` side.)

The *three*-dot form, as in `git log ...@{u}`, is fancier: it means *commits found by either left or right side, but not both*.  This finds commits `J-I` *and* `L-K`, in other words, for the graph drawn above.  The drawback here is that you can't tell which commit is on which "side".  Adding `--left-right` fixes that; adding `--graph` draws the graph; and adding `--boundary` tells Git to include commit `H` as well.  I don't really use this form though and do not bother with an alias for it: "incoming" and "outgoing" are my go-to aliases here.<sup>3</sup>

In any case, after *inspecting the incoming commits*, I choose whether to merge, rebase, or do something else entirely.  Then I do that.  I only want to do a fast-forward if I *can* do a fast-forward; in that case, having Git do it automatically with `git pull` is probably OK.  So setting `pull.ff` to `only` is what I want.

---

<sup>1</sup>I use the analogy of Git being like a party where everyone is named Bruce.  Someone comes up to you and says: "Hey Bruce, Bruce asked me to tell Bruce that Bruce is looking for him.  If you see Bruce, let him know, will you?"  In Git, this crazy re-use of the same word for multiple different things, over and over again, is very confusing—rather like it would be at this Bruce party.

<sup>2</sup>Again, Git isn't always very nice here: some Git commands use the two-dot notation for some other meaning.  The `git diff` command is the most obvious culprit here.  It uses both the two-dot and the three-dot notation to mean something different.  We won't cover that here.

<sup>3</sup>They are also, not exactly coincidentally, two Mercurial forms of `hg log`.